# How to change a list from one type to another with map function

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I have a livedata in my viewmodel that returns a `Resource<List<DrinkEntity>>` which I want it to return a `Resource<List<Drink>>` , I want to apply the map function in this method but I did not understand correctly the difference with the switchmap one

```
fun getTragosFavoritos() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try{
            emit(repo.getTragosFavoritos())
        }catch (e: Exception){
            emit(Resource.Failure(e))
        }
    }
```

I want to do the map right here, I have tried

```
fun getTragosFavoritos() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try{
            emit(repo.getTragosFavoritos())
        }catch (e: Exception){
            emit(Resource.Failure(e))
        }
    }.map {
   //But here I need to consume the Resource and I do that in my view, not here
}
```

The function above returns a `Resource<List<DrinkEntity>>` but it needs to return a `Resource<List<Drink>>`

I have an extension function that transform one list type to the other type already

```
fun List<DrinkEntity>.asDrinkList(): MutableList<Drink> = this.map {
    Drink(it.tragoId, it.imagen, it.nombre, it.descripcion, it.hasAlcohol)
}.toMutableList()
```

Comment: could your share code of `Resource`?

Answer (score 1):

Just observe the live data and use map if you a want to do that on the View:

```
val liveData: LiveData<List<Int>> = MutableLiveData(listOf(1,2,3,4))

liveData.observe(this, Observer {list ->
   val mappedList: List<String> =  list.map { item -> item.toString() }
})
```

Comment: the purpose of doing the map in the viewmodel is to prepare the data so the UI does not need to do any operation on the data provided, thats why I need it to be done in the viewmodel

Comment: Oh, I see. have you tried this? `emit(repo.getTragosFavoritos().asDrinkList())`

Comment: I cant since the value of getTragosFavoritos is of type Resource<List<DrinkEntity>>

Comment: Can you share the Resource<T> class declaration?